# Removing the dock only in activites overview

Tags: gnome, dock, activities-overview

I have the dash to dock extension installed, and I love it
But when I go to the activities overview by pressing Super, the dock gets overlapped with another bigger dock

This is how it looks
[image: This]

How do I remove the bigger dock that only appears in the overview?
Changing the Icon Size setting in settings only changes the size of the smaller dock, not the bigger one

I have Ubuntu version 21.10, gnome-shell version 40.5

Comment: Hey, the bigger dock is the dash to dock, you can't disable that but you can disable the smaller one!

Comment: If you want you can use autohide feature of the dash to dock

Comment: how did you instal dash to dock extension? there is a bug about this. when the dash to dock extension is updated, it will be resolved.

Comment: @Algnis Ah, didn't know that, thanks!